# How can I click on full height like the green box to go to the next Slide in AMP version (AMP Carousel)

Tags: slider, carousel, amp-html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eiv10.png)

I am looking for a way on the Internet and I have not yet found the possibility of moving by pressing up or down the arrow for (AMP Carousel), as shown in the image in green.
The problem is that in the AMP version I can't use javascript.

Does anyone have a suggestion or solution.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you can use custom JS in AMP but it has to be done in virtual DOM (Web Worker). Another workaround is to use `amp-selector` and `amp-bind` components. You can trigger actions on other AMP components using the `on` attribute. e.g. `on="select:action"` in `amp-selector` component.

**Here is a brief example of what you can do:**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>amp-carousel</title>
  <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
  <script async custom-element="amp-selector" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-selector-0.1.js"></script>
  <script async custom-element="amp-carousel" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-carousel-0.2.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <script async custom-element="amp-bind" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-bind-0.1.js"></script>
  <link rel="canonical" href="https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/components/amp-carousel/index.html">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
  <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
  <style amp-custom>
    .as-console-wrapper {
      display: none !important;
    }
    .relative {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 9;
    }
    .btn-box{
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 10;
      display: flex;
      top:0;
      bottom:0;
      left:0;
      right:0;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }
    .btn {
      width: 60px;
      height: 100%;
      font-size: 1.5rem;
      border: none;
      background-color: #83ff56;
      font-weight: 900;
    }
    amp-carousel.control-hide .amp-carousel-button {
      visibility: hidden;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class='relative'>
<amp-selector class='btn-box'  on="select:carousel.goToSlide(index=event.targetOption), AMP.setState({carouselIndex: event.targetOption})" layout="container">  
  <div [hidden]='carouselIndex != 0'></div>
  <button class='btn' option='0' hidden [hidden]='carouselIndex != 1' >
    <i [class]='carouselIndex > 0 ? "fas fa-chevron-left" : "fas fa-chevron-right"'></i>
  </button> 
  <button class='btn' option='1' [hidden]='carouselIndex != 2 && carouselIndex != 0'>
    <i [class]='carouselIndex > 1 ? "fas fa-chevron-left" : "fas fa-chevron-right"' class='fas fa-chevron-right'></i>
  </button>
  <button class='btn' option='2' hidden [hidden]='carouselIndex != 3 && carouselIndex != 1' [text]='carouselIndex > 2 ? "<" : ">"'></button>
  <button class='btn' option='3' hidden [hidden]='carouselIndex != 4 && carouselIndex != 2' [text]='carouselIndex > 3 ? "<" : ">"'></button>
  <button class='btn' option='4' hidden [hidden]='carouselIndex != 5 && carouselIndex != 3' [text]='carouselIndex > 4 ? "<" : ">"'></button>
  <button class='btn' option='5' hidden [hidden]='carouselIndex != 6 && carouselIndex != 4' [text]='carouselIndex > 5 ? "<" : ">"'></button>
  <button class='btn' option='6' hidden [hidden]='carouselIndex != 5' [text]='carouselIndex > 6 ? "<" : ">"'></button>
</amp-selector>

<amp-carousel id='carousel' class='control-hide' height="180" layout="fixed-height" type="slides" [slide]="carouselIndex"> 
  <amp-img src="https://fakeimg.pl/400x300/?retina=1&text=image00" width="400" height="180" alt="a sample image"></amp-img>
  <amp-img src="https://fakeimg.pl/500x300/?retina=1&text=image01" width="500" height="180" alt="another sample image"></amp-img>
  <amp-img src="https://fakeimg.pl/200x300/?retina=1&text=image02" width="200" height="180" alt="and another sample image"></amp-img>
  <amp-img src="https://fakeimg.pl/700x300/?retina=1&text=image03" width="700" height="180" alt="a sample image"></amp-img>
  <amp-img src="https://fakeimg.pl/400x300/?retina=1&text=image04" width="400" height="180" alt="another sample image"></amp-img>
  <amp-img src="https://fakeimg.pl/400x300/?retina=1&text=image05" width="400" height="180" alt="and another sample image"></amp-img>
  <amp-img src="https://fakeimg.pl/400x300/?retina=1&text=image06" width="400" height="180" alt="a sample image"></amp-img>
</amp-carousel>

</div>
</body></html>
```

Here is a [documentation](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-selector/) for `amp-selector` component.